# ¿Por qué cada vez que ejecuto un evento onClick, el dateTime no se actualiza?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

Me gustaría mezclar eventos de javascript con funcionalidades php para eliminar sesiones por inactividad.

La idea es que si pasan 15 minutos sin hacer ningún tipo de click en el contenido, la sesión se cerrará.

Tengo un evento nada más cargar la página que guarde en una variable php la hora en la que el usuario accede al contenido:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
        <?php
             $firstTime = new DateTime();
             echo "console.log('".$firstTime->format('H:i:s')."');";
        ?>
});
```

Y luego tengo una función que se ejecuta con un evento onClick sobre el contenido, y que crea otra variable para obtener la hora en la que el usuario está interactuando. Pero cuando lo muestro por consola, las horas son las mismas:

```
function clickWarning() {
        <?php
               $lastTime = new DateTime();
               echo "console.log('".$lastTime->format('H:i:s')."');";
        ?>
}
```

¿Por qué?
¿Debería manejar el tiempo únicamente con javacript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te está ocurriendo es que **PHP**, al ser un lenguaje de lado del servidor, se ejecuta primero que el **Javascript** que es del lado del cliente.

Esto ocasiona que básicamente ignore las funciones de **Javascript** que están determinando cuando la variable tiene que obtener el valor (las funciones `onclick` y `document.ready`) ya que al cargar la página lo primero que sucede es que se ejecuta todo el **PHP** obteniendo tu variable el mismo valor en las dos veces que le das valor, ya que se ejecutan casi a la vez.

La manera que considero más correcta de hacerse sería a través de una función **AJAX** que llame a un **PHP** que le devuelva la fecha. De esta manera podrías llamar a dicha función ya sea desde el `document.ready` o el evento `onclick` obteniendo los valores que necesitas.

Comment: No es que se ignore el javascript, es que se ejecuta en otro universo diferente. PHP no tiene ni idea de lo que sucede en el ordenador cliente, como bien dices, eso se lo tienes que enviar mediante ajax.

Comment: Entiendo, he querido mezclar un poco las cosas. Lo ideal entonces sería crear un fichero que maneje el tiempo local, y recoger el valor con ajax para hacer comparaciones?. Porque, que diferencia habría si utilizo directamente javascript para manejar el tiempo de uso?

Comment: El problema que podrías tener es que un objeto date instanciado desde **PHP** puede tener un valor distinto a uno creado desde **Javascript**, ya que el de **PHP** obtiene el valor de la configuración del servidor desde donde se ejecuta. Si este se encuentra en Inglaterra, por ejemplo, podría devolverte la fecha correspondiente a su zona horaria. Esto te ocasionaría problemas a la hora de tratar las sesiones de **PHP** tomando el tiempo desde Javascript.

Comment: Lo más confiable al trabajar con fecha y hora es traer la hora GMT desde el servidor y no la hora local del usuario dado que puede modificar la hora y hacer que tu aplicación se comporte de una forma que no corresponde, en tu caso dado que solo calculas el tiempo de inactividad puedes usar las funciones date o gmdate a menos que necesites mostrarle información al usuario sobre la fecha y hora.